# php md5 hash equal to java

Tags: java, php, md5

i just want working php md5 function(code) which generate equal result with below java code...

Normal php md5 function not giving equal result with this java code..

```
private static final String md5(String string) {
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        messageDigest.update(string.getBytes());
        byte[] arrby = messageDigest.digest();
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        int n = 0;
        block3 : do {
            if (n >= arrby.length) {
                return stringBuffer.toString();
            }
            String string2 = Integer.toHexString(255 & arrby[n]);
            do {
                String string3;
                if (string2.length() >= 2) {
                    stringBuffer.append(string2);
                    ++n;
                    continue block3;
                }
                string2 = string3 = "0" + string2;
            } while (true);

        } while (true);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException var1_7) {
        var1_7.printStackTrace();
return "";
    }
}
```

code edited...and example given....

String="fpwdxx-xx0xx-xx"+"8420474066"+"xx-xx"+"2.9"+"xx-xx"+"2016-09-14 21:13:25"+"xx-xx"+"AirTel"+"xx-xx"+""+"xx-xx"+"26b792f77e6f5157"+"xx-xx"+"911364603150705"+"xx-xx"+"A52+"+"xx-xx"+"4.2.2"+"z1t998044Fgrt...d";

Java Result: cfcb292130f3aa3cd49eed180e3d76a3

PHP Result: dd7e471b1a66a691097017c8de 2783a3

Comment: Can you give an example of input, what php gives you, and what the Java version gives you? It seems to be pretty standard.

Comment: OK. This Java code doesn't compile - the `break` should not be there. Removing it, and trying to run `md5` on "abc" gives exactly the same result as php. I'm going to vote to close this as unreproducible.

Comment: input example given...

Comment: Sigh. I run `php -r 'echo md5("fpwdxx-xx0xx-xx8420474066xx-xx2.9xx-xx2016-09-14 21:13:26f5157xx-xx911364603150705xx-xxA52+xx-xx4.2.2z1t998044Fgrt...d")."\n";'`. The result is `cfcb292130f3aa3cd49eed180e3d76a3`. Perhaps you are not constructing your string correctly in PHP. You are not actually using `+` to concatenate strings in PHP, are you?

Comment: yes u r abosolutely right....thanks got it now...problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

php has his own md5 function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

```
md5($string)
```

this is standard implementation, but php pads the value with an extra 0 in front so it's always 16 characters, so you can check this